# React Native with Firebase Problem: "Invariant Violoation: 'new NativEventEmitter()' requires a non-null argument., js engines: hermes

Tags: firebase, react-native

[ERROR: Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbw0j.jpg)

Situation: I followed the complete guild-lines to install firebase/all & firebase/store, but problem found.

Problem found after command 'npx react-native run-ios' run:
"Invariant Violoation: 'new NativEventEmitter()' requires a non-null argument., js engines: hermes at FirebaseApp (http://localhost:8081....)
at RCTView
at View
at RCTView
at RCTView
at AppContainer

Could anyone have suggestions to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Also: Please don't post screenshots of your code or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.